# Yii Form Model >> Check Other Fields Are Valid Inside A Custom Validation

Tags: php, yii

Let's assume that I have a form with a, b & c fields. I'm going to validate c using custom validation. Inside there, I need to check whether both a & b are already valid. That means, i need to validate c only if a & b are valid.

Following is a sample of my code.

```
public function rules() {
        return array(

                array('a', 'required'),
                array('b', 'numerical', 'min' => 18, 'max' => 99),                      
                array('c', 'mycustomvalidation')
        );
}

public function mycustomvalidation($attribute, $params) {

    if($this->validate(array('a', 'b'))) { // DO THE VALIDATION IF a & b ARE VALID ONLY

        $error = '';
        if($this->attributes[$attribute] > 1000)
            $error = $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute) . " must be lower than 1000.";

        if (!empty($error))
            $this->addError($attribute, $error);
    }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write in the controller:

```
if($model->validate(array('a','b')))
{
    if($model->validate(array('c')))
    {
        $model->save()
    }
}
```